# How to test if onclick: javascript:print() is working in a feature spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I have a link embedded in a page:

```
<%= link_to "<span class ='glyphicon glyphicon-print'></span>".html_safe, '#', onclick: 'javascript:print()',
  class: 'print_link', id: 'printable' %>
```

If I click it, then it opens a browser overlay to print the page. In a feature spec, how do I test that this browser overlay opens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That opens a system dialog which Capybara has no access to, so you can't really check it.  With most drivers you can verify the value of the onclick attribute by doing something like

```
expect(find(:link, 'printable')['onclick']).to eq 'javascript:print()'
```

which would verify the link is there with the correct click handler, but verifying the actual behavior really isn't possible